# Why does my perl fastcgi script does not open socket

Tags: perl, fastcgi

I am write a simple perl FasCGI script by [example](http://search.cpan.org/~skimo/FCGI-0.67/FCGI.PL)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use FCGI;

my $count = 0;
my $request = FCGI::Request();

while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n", ++$count);
}
```

than i am making this script executable and executing it in terminal, but instead of opening the socket, that script prints

> Content-type: text/html
>
> 1

and ends.
Why?

**UPDATE**

Thanks guys, but I don't understand one moment, how my script know, i installed or not web server module?And why i need server for normally run fastcgi script? for example when I run Catalyst fastcgi starter, I don't need any server, and I can run that script in any machine, without server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure FCGI expects your script to be invoked in some way from a webserver.  It isn't a webserver in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the **Installing FastCGI** section from the following link. I believe you are missing this.
http://www.intranetwerx.com/bookshelf2/linux/cgi/ch17_02.htm

Comment: fastcgi script is also a CGI script. But for fastcgi, the webserver sends the request to the fast CGI process over a socket. You'll find more clear detail about from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI#Implementation_details

Answer (score 0):

It's a debugging mode. Rather than dying because you didn't provide a proper Fast CGI environment, it simulates a single request.

```
unless ($req->IsFastCGI()) {
    return -1 if $run_once;

    $run_once = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

You do realize that Fast CGI is a communication protocol used to communicate between your script and a module in your web server, right? You need to have the web server module launch your script.